# wordpress - replace meta values in table

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, key-value

I have a "usermeta" table in db.

and there are some columns including meta_key and meta_value.

the delivery_location(meta_key) has same meta_value.

so I want to replace current meta_value to new value in deliery_location

(70982, 20, 'delivery_location', 'a:61:{i:0;s:47:"{lat:32.89030473256227, lng:-96.96264851172401}";i:1;s:47:"{lat:32.89359300394015, lng:-96.94936752319336}";i:60;s:0:"";}'),

my question is that how I can replace the all same meta_values at once in mysql?

[image]

Comment: Use serialize() and unserialize() https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-php-serialize-and-unserialize-function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all users using [get_users()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/). check the below code. code goes in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function update_all_user_delivery_location(){
    $users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );

    foreach ( $users as $key => $user ) {

        $delivery_location = get_post_meta( $user->ID, 'delivery_location', true );

        // modify your code here

        update_post_meta( $user->ID, 'delivery_location', $delivery_location );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'update_all_user_delivery_location', 10, 1 );
```